# @font-face not working (Shopify)

Tags: css, font-face, shopify

The src url is correct, but the the text just shows up as a regular serif. Maybe it has to do with Shopify?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStdCnNo.18';
src: url('http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0065/5242/files/tradegothicltstd-cn18-webfont.eot');
src: url('http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0065/5242/files/tradegothicltstd-cn18-webfont.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0065/5242/files/tradegothicltstd-cn18-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0065/5242/files/tradegothicltstd-cn18-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),

font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

and

```
#navbar #navpanel .mainnav ul.tier1 > li {
font-size:13px;
font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStdCnNo.18';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a simple mistake.

the last src url

```
url('http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0065/5242/files/tradegothicltstd-cn18-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
```

should end with `;` not `,`

I thought of deleting the question, but instead decided to answer it myself just in case somebody else makes the same mistake.